# Why Returning false even if executes the stored procedure

Tags: ado.net

```
public bool Update()
        {
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@EmpId", EmpId);
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
            {
                param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Name", DBNull.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                param[1] = new SqlParameter("@Name", Name);
            }
            if (Salary == null)
                param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Salary", DBNull.Value);
            else
                param[2] = new SqlParameter("@Salary", Salary);
            if (DateofBirth  == null)
                param[3] = new SqlParameter("@DateofBirth", DBNull.Value);
            else
                param[3] = new SqlParameter("@DateofBirth", DateofBirth);
            if (DeptId  == null)
                param[4] = new SqlParameter("@DeptId", DBNull.Value);
            else
                param[4] = new SqlParameter("@DeptId", DeptId);
            return (Convert.ToInt32(SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(CONNECTION_STRING, "InsertEmployee", param)) > 0);             
        }
```

Even if stored procedure executes, returning false.Why

Answer (score 3):

[ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) returns the number of rows affected.  Based off contextual clues it looks like the stored procedure didn't insert a row for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected by the command (e.g. for an INSERT or UPDATE).

This is not > 0 for a function or procedure, by definition - because the SQL system can't know how many rows the function or procedure might have affected.

[ref](http://www.mediachase.com/documentation/FileUploader/API/Mediachase.FileUploader.SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery_overload_8.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of your stored proc?

In that case, the stored procedures doesn't return the number of records that were affected by its operations, and ADO.NET's SqlCommand interprets that as a failure.